# Erro ao instanciar objeto dentro de um namespace

Tags: php, namespace, mpdf, trait

Estou tentando utilizar a biblioteca mpdf para imprimir em PDF.
Porém, está dando o seguinte erro na hora de instanciar a biblioteca:

```
Fatal error: Trait 'Mpdf\Strict' not found in C:\wamp64\www\jlrw\PHP\transporte\app\lib\mPdf\src\Mpdf.php on line 44
```

Eu não estou usando framework. A biblioteca mpdf está na pasta: `C:\wamp64\www\jlrw\PHP\transporte\app\lib`

Segue o código que estou usando em PHP:

```
session_start();
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$html = $_POST['dados'];

$sRoot = '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

require_once($sRoot . 'php' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'definicoes.php');

// Aqui eu trago o arquivo principal da biblioteca
require_once($sRoot . 'lib' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'mPdf' .
                              DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'src' .
                              DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Mpdf.php');

// "Autoload"
function AutoLoad($classname) {
   $filename = '..' .
               DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'lib' .
               DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'mPdf' .
               DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'src' .
               DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $classname . '.php';
   include_once($filename);
}

spl_autoload_register('AutoLoad');

$mpdf = new Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();

echo 'Impressão realizada.';
```

Em nenhum momento eu estou usando namespace em meu app.
A versão do meu PHP é a 7.2.4

O arquivo "Strict.php" está na pasta "src" da biblioteca. Não acredito que seja erro dela, mas sim a maneira que estou tentando instanciá-la para uso.

Comment: Acredito que o `mpdf` depende do Composer (ou equivalente) para carregar as classes internas. Nem Composer está utilizando?

Comment: Não cheguei a usar o composer também... baixei a biblioteca e coloquei ela na pasta. Será que é esse o problema?

Comment: Sim, vide código fonte da biblioteca. Em nenhum momento ele ele importa os arquivos de dependência, deixando essa responsabilidade para a ferramenta de *autoload* que preferir.

Comment: Instalei o mpdf via composer dentro da minha aplicação e diretamente na pasta "lib/mpdf", porém agora ele dá outro erro na hora de instanciar o objeto: "Uncaught Error: Class 'Mpdf' not found"... tá estranho...

Comment: Você importou o autoload do Composer?

Comment: Sim. Usei o comando "require_once" apontando diretamente para o "autoload.php" dentro da pasta "vendor" que o composer criou. Estou fazendo mais alguns testes aqui. Por enquanto, muito obrigado pela ajuda.